# Using Devise with class type inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, devise

How properly implement devise gem in multiple models, when I use CTI(class type inheritance)? I have 3 classes: Person(abstract class), Client and Employee that inherit. To design CTI, I add [dbview_cti](https://github.com/mvdamme/dbview_cti) gem. I want have register view for each inherited classes and shared rest function e.g. sign in. All tutorials describe implementation only for STI. I will be very grateful for detailed instructions.

Model Person

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.abstract_class = true
 self.table_name = 'people'
 cti_base_class
end
```

Model Client

```
class Client < Person
  cti_derived_class
end
```